# References for the computational complexity of training neural networks

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, references

I'm looking for a good review paper or book chapter that offers an accessible introduction to the computational complexity of training neural networks for classification problems. Some time back, I found a text book that stated that training an MLP network is NP-Complete, and there is [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/125-training-a-3-node-neural-network-is-np-complete.pdf) - but I haven't found much beyond that.

In particular, I'm trying to study questions like:

1. How is training complexity related to network topology ?
2. How is training complexity related to the complexity of the decision boundary?